# No error, but No Data resulting from VBA HTML Pull

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping

EDITED: So this one works for me.. I am looking to convert this to my purposes now.  I am trying to switch this to the title and price, but when I convert the line:
        Set links = .document.querySelectorAll(".s-item__link[href]")
to
        Set links = .document.querySelectorAll(".s-item__title [h3]")

It pulls "[object HTMLHeadingElement]" for each row - thoughts?

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetInfo()
Dim ie As New InternetExplorer, ws As Worksheet, t As Date
Const MAX_WAIT_SEC As Long = 10
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
With ie
    .Visible = True
    .Navigate2 "https://www.ebay.com/"

    While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

    ie.document.querySelector("#gh-ac").Value = "Bike"
    ie.document.querySelector("#gh-btn").Click

    While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

    Dim links As Object, i As Long, count As Long
    t = Timer
    Do
        On Error Resume Next
        Set links = .document.querySelectorAll(".s-item__link[href]")
        count = links.Length
        On Error GoTo 0
        If Timer - t > MAX_WAIT_SEC Then Exit Do
    Loop While count = 0
    For i = 0 To links.Length - 1
        ws.Cells(i + 1, 1) = links.item(i)
    Next
    .Quit
End With
```

End Sub

Comment: If you add `Debug.Print aEle` before `result = aEle`, does anything get outputted? (Turn on the Immediate Window to see, press CTRL+G in the VBEditor).  Are you sure it's looping through those classes? (Use `F8` to step through your code to see if it's running correctly).

Comment: Can you please include an example search term you are using

Comment: You never increment `y` in your loop, so you're overwriting your `result` in cell `C2` each time..

Comment: class name result__a doesn't appear in all search page results. At least not with my test cases.

Comment: Example Search Term:  Bike

Comment: What are the results you would like to parse from that site @RCarmody?

Comment: I've updated the code - I am looking to convert this to pull the title and price, but no luck... Thoughts on what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of doing a search for Bike on ebay and looping until links are present

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetInfo()
    Dim ie As New InternetExplorer, ws As Worksheet, t As Date
    Const MAX_WAIT_SEC As Long = 10
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate2 "https://www.ebay.com/"

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        ie.document.querySelector("#gh-ac").Value = "Bike"
        ie.document.querySelector("#gh-btn").Click

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        Dim links As Object, i As Long, count As Long
        t = Timer
        Do
            On Error Resume Next
            Set links = .document.querySelectorAll(".s-item__link[href]")
            count = links.Length
            On Error GoTo 0
            If Timer - t > MAX_WAIT_SEC Then Exit Do
        Loop While count = 0
        For i = 0 To links.Length - 1
            ws.Cells(i + 1, 1) = links.item(i)
        Next
        .Quit
    End With
End Sub
```